# Android OpenSL ES AAC decoder

Tags: android, android-ndk, aac, opensl

Is there any example source code how to decode AAC frames into PCM using Android OpenSL ES AAC decoder code? I need to decode AAC frame (with or without ADTS header) stored in memory buffer into PCM.